# How to get levels for each factor variable in R

Tags: r

I understand R assigns values to a factor vector alphabetically.  In this following example:

```
x <- as.factor(c("A","B","C","A","A","A","A","A","A","B","C","B","C","B","C","B","C"))
str(x)
```

This prints

```
Factor w/ 3 levels "A","B","C": 1 2 3 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 ...
```

Since I have only three levels it is easier to understand the level - value association i.e., A = 1, B = 2, so on and so forth.

In a scenario where I have hundreds of factors, is there a easier way to get it printed as a table that displays all the factors along with it level values like this:

```
Levels  Values
A        1
B        2
C        3
```

Comment: Why do you want to know the underlying numeric values that R assigns to each factor level? I ask because this generally wouldn't be an important thing to keep track of. Can you say more about what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: `mat <- cbind(as.character(x), as.integer(x));
 mat[!duplicated(mat),]`

Comment: @PKumar, I'd do `unique` first and then combine as a `data.frame` rather than a matrix.

Comment: @A5C1D2H2I1M1N2O1R2T1,  doing unique is a better choice. `x1 <- unique(x); cbind(as.character(x1), as.integer(x1))`

Comment: @PKumar, you realize that using `cbind` is going to coerce your data to be characters, right?

Comment: That is correct, I do agree at everything would be in characters, but OP didn't mentioned a type of outcome

Comment: `data.frame` would be obviously a better choice. `x <- unique(x) data.frame(x, as.integer(x))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why do you want to know the underlying numeric values that R assigns to each factor level? I ask because this generally wouldn't be an important thing to keep track of. Can you say more about what you're trying to accomplish? We may be able to provide additional advice if we know more about the underlying problem you're trying to solve. For now, below are examples of how to do what you ask that also show why the results might not be what you expect.

Do all the columns in your data frame have different combinations of the same underlying categories? If not, what you're asking for could give unexpected and undesirable results. Below are a couple of examples, based on a fake data frame with 3 factor columns, two of which are upper case letters and one of which is lower case letters.

```
# Fake data
set.seed(2)
x = c("C","A","B","C","A","A","A","A","A","A","B","C","B","C","B","C","B","C")
dat = data.frame(x=x,
                 y=sample(LETTERS[1:5], length(x), replace=TRUE),
                 z=sample(letters[1:3], length(x), replace=TRUE),
                 w=rnorm(length(x)))
```

Note that the numeric codes assigned to each factor level are not unique across columns. The lower case letters and the upper case letters can both have factor codes 1 through 3.

```
# Return a list with factor levels and numeric codes for each factor column
lapply(dat[ , sapply(dat, is.factor)], function(v) {
  data.frame(Levels=levels(unique(sort(v))),
             Values=as.numeric(unique(sort(v))))
  })
```

> ```
> $x
>   Levels Values
> 1      A      1
> 2      B      2
> 3      C      3
>
> $y
>   Levels Values
> 1      A      1
> 2      B      2
> 3      C      3
> 4      D      4
> 5      E      5
>
> $z
>   Levels Values
> 1      a      1
> 2      b      2
> 3      c      3
> ```

Another potential complication is whether the order of the factor levels is the same for different columns. As an example, let's change the factor order for one of the upper case columns. This creates a new issue in that the the same letter can have a different code value in different columns and the same code can be assigned to different letters. For example, `A` has code 1 in column `x` and code 5 in column `y`. Furthermore, code 1 is assigned to `E` in column `y`, rather than to `A`.

```
dat$y = factor(dat$y, levels = LETTERS[5:1]) 

# Return a list with factor levels and numeric codes for each factor column
lapply(dat[ , sapply(dat, is.factor)], function(v) {
  data.frame(Levels=levels(unique(sort(v))),
             Values=as.numeric(unique(sort(v))))
})
```

> ```
> $x
>   Levels Values
> 1      A      1
> 2      B      2
> 3      C      3
>
> $y
>   Levels Values
> 1      E      1
> 2      D      2
> 3      C      3
> 4      B      4
> 5      A      5
>
> $z
>   Levels Values
> 1      a      1
> 2      b      2
> 3      c      3
> ```

Comment: I am trying to run a Logistic Regression using one of the vector with character values as a dependent variable.  Though this vector is binary, some of the independent variables have multiple elements in them.  I was trying to figure out how the factor values assigned by R impacts the interpretation of results.

Comment: The underlying numeric codes are not important for interpreting a regression model. However, with categorical independent variables, the first level (letter `A` in your example) will be the reference category, which is omitted. The coefficients of the other categories will all be relative to the omitted reference category. To change the reference category, you can change the factor order (in my second example, `E` becomes the first category, and therefore the reference, when that variable is used as an independent variable in a regression model.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation though....truly appreciate....your second example of sorting the element order within a variable and assigning the factor values helped me in understanding how I could use independent variables with multiple factors in them..

Comment: Another way to change the reference category: `dat$y = relevel(dat$y, ref="C")` will change the reference category to `C`.

Comment: When dealing with factors, I find the `forcats` package particularly helpful.